# using visual studio 2013 ide for other things

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-addins

I love VS2013 with the Solarized-Dark theme.
I would like to use the IDE to do other tasks, if possible.
I noticed that SQL Server 2014 uses the VS2010 IDE for it's interface.
I realize that might be because they have the source to the IDE - LOL.

I'm just wondering if I can create an add-in, or in some other way USE the VS2013 IDE for other purposes - creating tabs and hosting my own controls in those tabs - and of course modifying the menus.

The rest of the look/feel - I'd like to remain as I think it's superior for any programmer. The custom (ie; NON-Windows7) scrollbars - the tabs - the Solarized theme - are all things I would want to keep.

Any pointers or advice would be greatly appreciated.
I've use VS since it's inception, but never tried to develop add-ins or extend the IDE in any way.

THANKS in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find an overview and deep content about Visual Studio Extensibility (VXS) on my web site:

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/overview/vs/

You can extend the Visual Studio IDE or reuse the Visual shell for your own purposes. SQL Server uses the Visual Studio Shell, Integrated Mode.

Comment: THANK YOU for the reply!  Your site is very useful and has many great links all in one place!  In my research I did learn about the isolated shell, which seems to be exactly what I need.  MSDN has a nice example template that is very educational.  Now if I can learn how to add a dynamic tool window (tabbed) I'll be in good shape!

PS: The real trick was figuring out how to get the isolated shell app to use the extension that provides additional custom themes! LOL That took a while!